# Swift UIBarButtonItem created using UIButton's frame not set properly

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uibutton, uibarbuttonitem

I need to display a toolBar with 3 elements (two buttons on either side and a label in the center). Each of them are created using a custom UIButton. Here is the code:

```
 let toolBar = UIToolbar()
        toolBar.barStyle = .default
        toolBar.sizeToFit()

        let titleButton = UIButton(type: .custom)
        titleButton.titleLabel?.numberOfLines = 0
        titleButton.setTitle(self.toolBarLabelString, for: UIControlState.normal)
        titleButton.setTitleColor(.darkGray, for: .normal)
        titleButton.frame = CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.width - 180, height: 40)
        titleButton.contentEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 20.0, bottom: 0, right: -14.0)
        //titleButton.backgroundColor = .yellow

        let doneButton = UIButton(type: .custom)
        doneButton.setTitle("Done", for: UIControlState.normal)
        doneButton.frame = CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 0, width: 40, height: 40)
        doneButton.contentEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0.0, bottom: 0, right: -24.0)
        doneButton.setTitleColor(.green, for: .normal)
        doneButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(CreateRecipeViewController.donePicker), for: .touchUpInside)
        //doneButton.backgroundColor = .yellow

        let cancelButton = UIButton(type: .custom)
        cancelButton.frame = CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 0, width: 40, height: 40)
        cancelButton.contentEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: -14.0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
        cancelButton.setTitle("Cancel", for: UIControlState.normal)
        cancelButton.setTitleColor(.red, for: .normal)
        cancelButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(CreateRecipeViewController.cancelPicker), for: .touchUpInside)


        let titleBarButton = UIBarButtonItem(customView: titleButton)
        let spaceButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.fixedSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
        spaceButton.width = 20

        let cancelBarButton = UIBarButtonItem(customView: cancelButton)
        //let cancelBarButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem : .cancel, target: nil, action:  #selector(CreateRecipeViewController.cancelPicker))
        //let doneBarButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem : .done, target: nil, action:  #selector(CreateRecipeViewController.donePicker))
        let doneBarButton =  UIBarButtonItem(customView: doneButton)

        toolBar.setItems([cancelBarButton, spaceButton, titleBarButton, spaceButton, doneBarButton], animated: false)
        toolBar.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
```

I see that the buttons on either side are not being displayed as they are overlapped by the center element. I tried setting a frame and contenEdgeInsets, but that has not helped.

I will appreciate any help / ideas with this.

Thank you!

Comment: Hmm, I can't reproduce your overlap description? Running your code by adding the `toolBar` as a subview to the view controller's view showed all three items without any overlap? **Edit:** How large is your title string in characters?

Comment: You are right, for shorter strings, the buttons are rendered fine. When the string is larger than say 50 characters, then it starts overlapping, although the numberoflines is set to 0 which should span it to multiple lines.any thoughts?

Comment: Is the requirement that the title will be over 50 characters?

Comment: Yes it can be, I ended up reducing the font of the string incase it exceeded a limit. That is working okay as of now. Thanks for your help!